# Style the header of TabControl?

Tags: wpf

I need to set the `FontSize` for each TabItem header, I tried with this:

```
<TabControl>
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="HeaderedItemsControl">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="5" />
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
        <TabItem Header="Analisys" />
        <TabItem Header="Compare" />
```

But the header font size is still the same, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your TargetType must be TabItem not HeaderedItemsControl.

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="5" />
</Style>
```